# Send URL parameters to api in xamarin API

Tags: android, xamarin, url-parameters

I am using xamarin for one of my chat application in college project
in which I use URL parameters to send chat messages to API
my problem is when there is a space in the message the URL breaks and application crashes.
I want the solution in which I can convert those spaces to %20 standards so that API recognizes that it is a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should search properly before you ask the question**

> this solution is not just limited for Xamarin

if this is your api link: "http://yourapi/chat?msg=yourmsg"

and incoming msg is say "Your Msg"

and you are getting "http://yourapi/chat?msg=your msg"

this surely is not going to work

your desired string must be: "http://yourapi/chat?msg=your%20msg" (If your api recognizes this well)

then this is the solution for you

```
// you Need to add a Reference to the System.Web assembly.
using System.Web;
var etMsg= FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText);
string msg =etMsg.Text.ToString ();
string url = "http://yourapi/chat?msg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg);
```

Any Special Characters can be url encoded with this solution

**Happy Coding**

Comment: So this is the generic question not only for xamarin?

Comment: any .Net platform, this can be the solution you may say. there are similar methods for java as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use URLencoder or simply use String replace method e.g. "yourParam".replace ("", "%20").

Check outhe below link for more details :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html