# How to Pass JsonString As a Parameter in Android WebAPI

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

```
string sortbyObj ="{'SortName':'DueDate','SortType':'asc'}";

string FiltersObj = "{'StartTime':'1/8/2016','EndTime':'3/8/2018','Ovedue':false,'Status':-1,'Priority':-1,'AssignedTo':-9999,'FollowUpBy':-9999,'Mytasks':false,'StartsWith':'','Endswith':''}";

string apiUrl = MainActivity.GetData("http://" + MainActivity.IPAddress + "/JTASKTest/api/jtasks/GetItemList?uName=admin&tgId=1&sortbyObj='"+sortbyObj.ToString()+"'&FiltersObj='"+FiltersObj.ToString()+"'");
```

I am trying to send string as a Parameter But it is giving 'Input string Formate not correct' Exception . Please Help Me how can i send this two Strings as a parametrs Through WebApi

Comment: does your API recognize the url encoded json string?

Comment: try to encode with `UTF-8` format before sending it...

Comment: public List<String> GetItemList(string uName, int tgId, string sortbyObj, string FiltersObj)
        {}  I am using Api Function Like this

Comment: i mean while passing your json in url pass it with `URLEncoder`

Comment: You may have to use string urldecode ( string $str ) in your API if it is in PHP.

Comment: I am Using DotNet Web API

Comment: can you post full error massage .?

Comment: and i think your json string is also wrong your single quote `'` should be double quote with back slash `\"`

Comment: after using encode format it is working. Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API recognizes the url encoded Json String then I would suggest you to use something like this

```
string url = "http://yourapi/chat?msg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg);
```

Detail answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585355/4321201)

in your case:

```
string apiUrl = MainActivity.GetData("http://" + MainActivity.IPAddress +"/JTASKTest/api/jtasks/GetItemList?uName=admin&tgId=1&sortbyObj='"+  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sortbyObj.ToString())+"'&FiltersObj='"+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FiltersObj.ToString()));
```

but in this case you should have to make sure that your API understands the URL Encoded JSON

Comment: After using encode format working now. thanks for your help  Akshay Kulkarni